# How to refactor the return of a generic method to an interface and all its implementations

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, refactoring

I would change the return type declared in an interface, which is implemented in 10 other about class method .
I'm using eclipse as IDE ,
the signature of the current method is:

```
public List<T> findById(int id);
```

and what I need

```
public T findById(int id);
```

Regards, Santiago

Comment: I don't think that eclipse supports such automatic refactorings, since presumably there is some change that you would need to make in the method bodies of your implementations so that it returns a single element instead of a list. Given that there are only 10 implementations, would it be faster to suck it up and change it manually?

Comment: Andy right in this case would be manually easy, but there should be an automated way .
Because if we think of a large system, and a method developer signs wrong , change it manually would be tedious

Comment: Changing the signature is (reasonably) straightforward, but there is no single way to implement the change from returning a list to returning a single element - do you return the first element, last element, min, max, average, some other combination of elements... the list of possibilities is infinite. You could spend the time trying to implement the refactoring using eclipse's framework, but sometimes simple-and-repetitive gets you there faster.

Comment: @AndyTurner Another possibility may be to declare the Same method with the new firm , but neither how to overwrite in the classes that implement the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @[Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) states in the comments you can't automatically refactor returning a list to returning one of the lists elements. However there are steps to take to do the interface refactoring safely.

1. Rename the list returning method in the interface.
2. For the most common solution, returning the first element for instance, use TDD to write the new object returning method in one of your implementations. The new method should call the old method, and return the new return type. Don't use the example below it is clearly unsafe and will lead to a stack dump at some point.

   ```
   @Override
   public T findById(int id){
       List<T> res = findById(id);
       return res.get(1);
    }
   ```
3. Update the interface to include the new method signature.
4. For each class that uses the same solution already implemented, copy and paste the new method written in step 2.
5. For any other desired implementations repeat steps 2 and 4.

If the method was an abstract method on a baseclass the initial method in step 2 would be written on the base class.